# Generate samples from data following normal distribution but with new mean

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

I have a vector of numbers that is

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(8334, 1.456977, 0.3552899)
mean(x)
[1] 1.454307
```

Essentially, I want to randomly sample 2000 numbers from `x` such that mean of this sample is lower.

The key is I don't want to generate new random numbers but only sample from `x`, without replacement, such that I get a subset with a different mean.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: use `sample` inside `rnorm` and select a mean lesser than the value you are looking for. `TestVector = rnorm(8334, 1.456977, 0.3552899)
rnorm(sample(TestVector, 8000), 0.5,0.3552899)`

Comment: @JasonMathews how does that sample from an existing vector? The following code returns `FALSE`. - `set.seed(1);x <- rnorm(8334, 1.456977, 0.3552899);y <- rnorm(sample(x, 2000), 0.5,0.3552899);all(y %in% x) # [1] FALSE`

Comment: I think it still generates numbers randomly. ```> table(TestVector %in% SampledVector)

FALSE 
 8334``` Is there a way to sample from the existing vector so I get exactly the same numbers?

Comment: My bad. Should have  been more careful.

Comment: @naeum do you really want a random subset of your original vector or any subset will do?

Comment: Hi Shree, yes. I would ilke to subset randomly as I still want a normal distribution. Subsetting leads to non-normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing rejection sampling, i.e. sampling 2000 numbers from your vector until you hit one sample that fulfills the desired properties?

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(8334, 1.456977, 0.3552899)
m_x <-mean(x)

y <- sample(x, 2000)
while(mean(y) >= m_x)
    y <- sample(x, 2000)

mean(y)
#> [1] 1.4477
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This should be quite fast since there is an (roughly) even chance for the new mean to be greater or smaller than the old one.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf! This seems to be closest to what I am looking for so far!

Answer (score 2):

This method is not truly *"random"* as it only picks from values that are smaller than `mean(x)`. Let me know if this is good enough for you -

```
set.seed(1)

x <- rnorm(8334, 1.456977, 0.3552899)

mean(x)
[1] 1.454307

y <- sample(x, 2000, prob = x <= mean(x)) # x > mean(x) has 0 chance of getting sampled

all(y %in% x)
[1] TRUE

mean(y)
[1] 1.170856
```

This is effectively the same as -

```
z <- sample(x[x <= mean(x)], 2000)

all(z %in% x)
[1] TRUE

mean(z)
[1] 1.172033
```

Also, for 2000 values, the lowest possible `mean` is this -

```
mean(sort(x)[1:2000])
[1] 0.9847526
```

**UPDATE -**

Here's one way to get random sample from both sides of `mean(x)` although it is arbitrary and I don't know if this would guarantee sample mean less than `mean(x)`. -

```
z <- sample(x, 2000, prob = (x <= mean(x)) + 0.1)

mean(z)
[1] 1.225991

table(z <= mean(x))

FALSE  TRUE 
  202  1798
```

Comment: Is there a better alternative to generating multiple combinations using `combn` function and checking for their mean less than the original mean?

Comment: I guess with `combn` you'd essentially be doing a brute force search. It's not going to scale well.

Comment: It more looks like `nsum` problem to me . https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem

Comment: Thanks @Shree! I think this is so far the closest to what I would like to do.

Comment: @naeum See updated answer. I still think there might be a better way. Hoping someone else can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

randomize normal distribution for the example

```
x= rnorm(8334,1.45,0.355)
```

pick a sample of 2000 nums

```
y= sample(x,2000)
```

lower y mean by 0.5

```
y=y-05
```

increase y's sd by 1.5

```
y= y*1.5
```

now the sd and the mean of Y will be about

```
mean(y)# ~0.9325603
sd(y)# ~0.5348885
```

hope it is the answer you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Shay. I will expand in my original query why I need to keep the original numbers. Your approach still gives me different numbers at the end.